# ReactJS Ant design select component mock change event

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, antd

Having a component MyComp which contains a [Select Ant component](https://ant.design/components/select/) and willing to test MyComp to make sure that handlers are correct and being called

```
class MyComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        this.props.doSomething();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Select onChange={this.props.handleChange}>
                <Option value={"Op0"} >Opt0</Option>
                <Option value={"Op1"} >Opt1</Option>
                <Option value={"Op2"} >Opt2</Option>
            </Select>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to be able to test it as follows:

```
it('calls the right callback', () => {
    const Option = Select.Option;
    const mockHandler = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComp handleChange ={mockHandler}/>);
    let select = wrapper.find(Select);
    select.simulate("onChange"); // also tried 'change'
    expect(mockHandler).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

Please bare in mind that it's 'mount' not shallow, so it actually renders children components

Comment: First of you can check that `select ` is what you expect by `console.log(select.debug())`. Then you could try `select.prop('onChange')()` instead of `simulate`

Comment: @AMTourkey you can try with wrapper.find('Select').

Comment: Thanks @AndreasKöberle! that actually worked!

Comment: @javed It's a custom component not the default html element

Answer (score 1):

As one approach you can use

```
select.prop('onChange')()
```

instead of `select.simulate`.

---

Additional you can open the antd select menu, check the values and go on with testing (depending on the used antd version).

In antd V3 you can use a simple `fireEvent.click`

```
// Opens the Drop down
fireEvent.click(getByText("Value 1"));
```

But with antd V4 you need to use `mouseDown` call

```
const elt = getByTestId('your-select-test-id').firstElementChild;
fireEvent.mouseDown(elt); // THIS WILL OPEN THE SELECT !
expect(getByText('Option from Select')).toBeInTheDocument(); // WORKS !
```

See depending [github issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23009).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but another solution to get rid of all the pain trying to interact with Ant Design Selects with Jest would be to mock the Select component, by placing [this kind of mock](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21080#issuecomment-738399118) in a Jest setup file (or in a particular test suite only). By doing so, all Select will be replaced by good old native selects, which are more friendly in a unit test context.

It may also be a good thing to decouple unit tests from a UI library that could change (or be completely removed...), and it can make your tests faster too (UI components like Ant Design Selects can be complicated).

Using this mock you can do cool things like that (I'm using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/) but this should work with Enzyme I guess) :

```
// Assuming a <Select data-testid="mySelect">...</Select> in component tested

// Update the selected option, triggering a onChange event
// No more click / mouseDown the input, find the right option in virtual list...
fireEvent.change(getByTestId('mySelect'), { target; { value: 'optionValue' } });

const options = getByTestId('mySelect').querySelectorAll('option');
expect(options[0].textContent).toEqual('first option text');
expect(options[0]).toHaveValue('option1Value');

// or test all in one shot
expect(Array.from(options).map(o => o.getAttribute('value'))).toEqual(['value1', 'value2']);
```

So far this is really more convenient than interacting with real Selects.